# Add popup with GeoJSON data

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, popup

I want to display popup with the data item, such as: name, coordinates, stationID, Attribute.

But my code has some problem that can't run.

```
<html lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
          integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
          crossorigin="" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
            integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og=="
            crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="height: 500px; border: 1px solid #AAA;"></div>
    <script>

        var osmUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, { maxZoom: 20, attribution: osmAttrib });
        var map = L.map('map').setView([24.151687694799833,120.64116954803465
              ], 15).addLayer(osm);              //顯示地圖
        L.control.scale().addTo(map);

        $.getJSON("https://sta.ci.taiwan.gov.tw/STA_Rain/v1.0/Things?$expand=Locations&$select=name,properties&$count=true", function (data) {
            var markerGroup = L.featureGroup();
            data.value.forEach(function (itemData, itemInd) {
                var latLng = L.latLng(itemData.Locations[0].location.coordinates[1], itemData.Locations[0].location.coordinates[0]);
                var myMarker = L.marker(latLng).addTo(markerGroup);
                myMarker.bindPopup('ID: ' + itemData.properties.stationID + '<br />Name: ' + itemData.properties.stationName);  

                onEachFeature (itemData, layer) {
                    layer.bindPopup("<p></p>"
                        + itemData.name + "</p>"
                        + itemData.properties.Attribute +
                        "</p>Attribute: "
                    );
                };
            }).addTo(map);

            markerGroup.addTo(map);
            map.fitBounds(markerGroup.getBounds());          
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my GeoJSON:

```
https://sta.ci.taiwan.gov.tw/STA_Rain/v1.0/Things?$expand=Locations&$select=name,properties&$count=true
```

Comment: Can you describe with a little more detail what you mean by 'can't run'? Do you get any errors in console?

Comment: Can't run means my leaflet didn't display nothing,after I add this code : onEachFeature (itemData, layer) {
                    layer.bindPopup("<p></p>"
                        + itemData.name + "</p>"
                        + itemData.properties.Attribute +
                        "</p>Attribute: "
                    );
                };
            }).addTo(map);

Comment: Sorry, is my code has any error?

Comment: @TomazicM    Should I use if loop?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this statement (which is completely out of place in this case)? Popup is already bound to marker with `myMarker.bindPopup`.

Comment: @TomazicM I want If I click the Marker and it will popup with GeoJSON's information. (information such as：name，coordinates，stationID，Attribute)  for example: this URL you can see     http://jsfiddle.net/1Lshjdxq/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already explanied in answer to this question [Why the icon can't display with my JSON data on Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328466/why-the-icon-cant-display-with-my-json-data-on-leaflet), your JSON is not GeoJSON, so it's not converted to features and standard feature methods cannot be used.

Properties that you want to display in popup are members of `itemData.properties` object, so you have to iterate through `itemData.properties` keys and construct your popup by getting key values:

```
$.getJSON("https://sta.ci.taiwan.gov.tw/STA_Rain/v1.0/Things?$expand=Locations&$select=name,properties&$count=true", function (data) {
    var markerGroup = L.featureGroup();
    data.value.forEach(function (itemData, itemInd) {
        var latLng = L.latLng(itemData.Locations[0].location.coordinates[1], itemData.Locations[0].location.coordinates[0]);
        var myMarker = L.marker(latLng).addTo(markerGroup);
        var popupContent = '';
        for (var key in itemData.properties) {
          popupContent = popupContent + key + ':  ' + itemData.properties[key] + '</br>';        
        };
      myMarker.bindPopup(popupContent);
    }).addTo(map);

    markerGroup.addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(markerGroup.getBounds());          
});
```

Comment: Sorry,I try to run,but this code can't run correct. It's also can't display the marker.  Should I change the "key"  ?

Comment: What does it mean "can't run correct"?

Comment: I use your code you give me, and even the marker can't display. Before I use the above code(in my artical),the marker can display on the map.
Sorry,  iterate through itemData.properties keys and construct your popup by getting key values: this sentences I can't understand

Comment: Do you get any error in debug console?

Comment: no. So I want to ask you the code you give me,      popupContent = popupContent + key + ':  ' + itemData.properties[key] + '</br>';     Should I change the key ?

Comment: That should not be the problem. `key` is just variable name, it can be any. Can you put your code on JSFiddle or CodePen?

Comment: Yes,but I have never used it before, or can I get your email?    https://codepen.io/cow61127/pen/QeyKYW

Comment: If you want help from community you'll have to learn it sooner or later.

Comment: OK, my CodePen. codepen.io/cow61127/pen/QeyKYW

Comment: You published just barebone code without external .css and .js library links. To make code working, you must include them through `Settings` and then `CSS` and `JavaScript` sections.

Comment: Remove reference to `leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js` from your code and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is the problem,after I remove it then it can run successfully.

Comment: Can I ask you, what the reason that I remove reference to leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js from my code , and the code can run successfully? Thanks!

Comment: Because it's very old version of Leaflet and you included it after newest version `leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js`, so it overriden the newest version.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues:

1. Data is not really GeoJSON, check http://geojsonlint.com/ to see if your data displays. The URL you posted has issues.
2. In your script area, you are using Leaflet 1.5.1 and Leaflet 0.7.3.  You don't need the older version.
3. Here is a simple write up for displaying GeoJSON data, it may help. http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/Simple/indexMap1.html You are bring your data in like it's just JSON not GeoJSON. You don't need to loop through your data for it to display real GeoJSON data, the Leaflet code handles this.

If you want to do this as JSON here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSON - Leaflet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
          integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
          crossorigin="" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
            integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og=="
            crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        #map {
            width: 800px;
            height: 600px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div id='map'></div>
<script>

//var url = 'https://www.mcdonalds.com/googleapps/GoogleRestaurantLocAction.do?method=searchLocation&latitude=42.837849&longitude=-73.77132&radius=80.45&maxResults=50&country=us&language=en-us&showClosed=&hours24Text=Open%2024%20hr';   

var url = 'MCDon.json'; //used the above URL to create this local JSON file and avoid CORs error.

        var map = L.map('map').setView([42.787,  -73.69216], 10); 

    var osm=new L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{ 
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'}).addTo(map);

    var mcd = L.featureGroup();

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) { 
            var lng = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0];
            var lat = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates[1];
            var Line1 = data.features[i].properties.addressLine1;
                        var Line2 = data.features[i].properties.addressLine2;
                        var MCDs = L.marker([lat,lng]).bindPopup("&ltb&gtAddress: &lt/b&gt" + Line1 + "&lt/br&gtRegion: " + Line2);
            mcd.addLayer(MCDs);
        } 
    });
    mcd.addTo(map);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note my URL issues a CORS error, so I used it to create a JSON file, and I used that instead.  This example works with that data.