# Adding JSON layer in Leaflet just like GeoJSON data?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, json

I am trying to add different layers to a leaflet map. Now i really want these layers in order to add features like zoom. With GeoJSON file this was easy but I am not getting a good way to plot array data from JSON response of this sort `[[1,2],[ 3,4],[5,6]]` :

So basically my question is how can I group latlng points together to form a layer equivalent to how layer is provided in L.geoJson.

I have done some work in this direction:

```
placePointsOnMap(){
        let markerParams = {
            stroke: true,
            radius: 3,
            fillColor: 'blue',
            color: 'black',
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            fillOpacity: 1,

        };
        for(let i of this.state.points){
            console.log("ii", i);
            L.circleMarker(i, markerParams).addTo(this.miniMap);
        }
    }
```

But this is not how I want points to be displayed, instead I want this to be a part of layers feature provided by leaflet `allLayers = L.layerGroup([]);`

```
this.geojsonPointsLayer = L.geoJSON(this.state.geoJSON, {
            onEachFeature: this.onEachFeatureFunction.bind(this),
            pointToLayer: this.pointToLayerFunction.bind(this),
            filter: this.filterPointsAsRequired.bind(this)
        });
```

Comment: Answer to this question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329499/add-popup-with-geojson-data/329563#329563 might get you going in the right direction.

Comment: @TomazicM that actually helped me out ...

Comment: my solution for this scenario:

```addingRoadPoint(){
        const markerGroup = L.featureGroup();
        const markerParams = {
            stroke: true,
            radius: 3,
            fillColor: 'blue',
            color: 'black',
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            fillOpacity: 1,

        };
        this.state.points.forEach((latLng, index)=>{
            L.circleMarker(latLng, markerParams).addTo(markerGroup);            
        })
        markerGroup.addTo(this.miniMap);
        this.miniMap.fitBounds(markerGroup.getBounds()); 
    } ```

Comment: Saying it duplicate is misleading. Area of research in this question is different. It has got nothing to do with popup. Here i am trying to work with pure json instead of geoJson. For geojsons, leaflet is providing inbuilt layer called L.geoJson. So basically my question was how i can group latlng points together to form a layer.

Comment: Not quite true. Title of question is endeed about popup, but real problem was in JSON being treated as GeoJSON, and the solution pointed out how to read JSON and convert JSON data to geometry.

Comment: If you have solution to your own problem, then post it as answer so others may profit from it. It's almost impossible to find solutions in comments.

Comment: i did write. Please checkout the third comment by me. Let me post it again  ```addingRoadPoint(){ const markerGroup = L.featureGroup(); const markerParams = { stroke: true, radius: 3, fillColor: 'blue', color: 'black', weight: 2, opacity: 1, fillOpacity: 1, }; this.state.points.forEach((latLng, index)=>{ L.circleMarker(latLng, markerParams).addTo(markerGroup); }) markerGroup.addTo(this.miniMap); this.miniMap.fitBounds(markerGroup.getBounds()); }```