# Loading GeoJSON data to Leaflet overlay?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, api, overlay, url

I am trying to get [GeoJSON](https://geojson.org/) data from an API URL to an overlay.

Code;

```
// - GET GEOJSON DATA WITH AJAX TO OVERLAY REGION - //
// Get the data
var regions = $.ajax({
    url:"https://public.opendatasoft.com/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=sverige-lan-counties-of-sweden&q=&lang=en&rows=37&start=0&facet=id&facet=lan_namn&facet=geo_point_2d",
    dataType: "json",
    success: console.log("Data successfully loaded!"),
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.statusText)
    }
})

$.when(regions).done(function() {
    var regions = document.getElementById('lan_namn');
    L.geoJSON(regions, {
        pointToLayer: function (latlng) {
            return L.circleMarkers(latlng, {
                radius:6,
                opacity: .8
            })            
            .bindPopup("<p><b> " + records.fields.lan-namn + "</b></p>");
        }
    })        
});
regions.addLayer(regions);
```

```json
{
  "nhits": 21,
  "parameters": {},
  "records": [
{
  "datasetid": "sverige-lan-counties-of-sweden",
  "recordid": "2bf8cfbfbd622b8d44987da4a8fdc5f957d2ed01",
  "fields": {
  "geo_shape": {},
  "id": "08",
  "lan_namn": "Kalmar län",
  "geo_point_2d": [
    57.2009990015,
    16.1929043382
  ]
},
"geometry": {
  "type": "Point",
  "coordinates": [
    16.1929043382,
    57.2009990015
  ]
},
"record_timestamp": "2019-07-15T12:39:19.034000+00:00"
},
{
  "datasetid": "sverige-lan-counties-of-sweden",
  "recordid": "b55c4a362b22739db2cdc4896ce10d1be93feb7c",
  "fields": {
    "geo_shape": {
      "type": "MultiPolygon",
      "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          [
            15.401945130895863,
            62.00965766023548
          ]
      ............
```

Comment: is there a console error?

Comment: Error: regions.addLayer is not a function..

Comment: Data you are trying to load is not GeoJSON but only JSON. See answer to similar problem: [Why the icon can't display with my JSON data on Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328466/why-the-icon-cant-display-with-my-json-data-on-leaflet)

Comment: @TomazicM you referring to switching the coordinates to lat lng?

Comment: You are adding regions to regions (regions.addLayer(regions)) and the region in the jQuery function stays in the function. Additionally the first regions variable is not a Layer

Comment: @DavideRaro I have an overlay called region and a variable called region, so was trying to assign the data there -.-

Comment: @LiahCheston, but you can't have 2 variables with the same name. Then the second "region" (the overlay) is declared in a function and it stays in the function while you try to call it from outside the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data are not in the correct geojson format, so you have to parse it by your self:

```
var fg = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
fetch("https://public.opendatasoft.com/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=sverige-lan-counties-of-sweden&q=&lang=en&rows=37&start=0&facet=id&facet=lan_namn&facet=geo_point_2d%22")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data =>{
        data.records.forEach((d)=>{
          var geojson = d.fields.geo_shape;
          console.log(geojson);
          var layer = L.GeoJSON.geometryToLayer(geojson);
          fg.addLayer(layer);


          var point = L.GeoJSON.coordsToLatLng(d.geometry.coordinates);
          var circle = L.circleMarker(point,{
            radius:6,
            opacity: .8
          }).bindPopup("<p><b> " + d.fields.lan_namn + "</b></p>");
          fg.addLayer(circle);
        });
        map.fitBounds(fg.getBounds())
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least five reasons why your code cannot work:

1. API you are using to get data for GeoJSON layer does return JSON data, but this data does not have GeoJSON structure (see https://geojson.org/). To get required GeoJSON data you have to add parameter `format=geojson` to your API.
2. With `var regions = document.getElementById('lan_namn');` you assign DOM element to `regions` and then use this as input to creating GeoJSON layer. That makes no sense, input has to be GeoJSON object.
3. Your definition of `pointToLayer` function is wrong. It should have two paramters, first is point feature and second point coordinates.
4. In your popup definition you are using `records.fields.lan-namn`, which does not exist.
5. Statement `regions.addLayer(regions);` makes no sense, you cannot add something to itself.

Below is code that works:

```
var regions = L.geoJSON(null, {
 pointToLayer: function (pointFeature, latlng) {
      return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
          radius:6,
          opacity: .8
      })            
      .bindPopup("<p><b> " + pointFeature.properties.lan_namn + "</b></p>");
  }  
});


$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "https://public.opendatasoft.com/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=sverige-lan-counties-of-sweden&q=&lang=en&rows=37&start=0&facet=id&facet=lan_namn&facet=geo_point_2d&format=geojson",
  success: function(data) {
    $(data.features).each(function(key, data) {
        regions.addData(data);
    });
    regions.addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(regions.getBounds());
  },
  error: function(err) {
    console.log('error geojson')
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down, explaining errors clearly. I need that, am still learning. I had 1 and 5. 4 I was sure of since the json order. 2 and 3 I knew just unsure of how..and the order of it.. and yes it works! More important, now I know why. Still a little confused over the 'key' parameter. Have to go over it some more, but Thank you!